# Use many to many relation to generate columns like a pivot

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables called Project, ProjectMember and User, where ProjectMember is a junction table and has a column MemberType (valid values are 0,1 and 2). I need to return all projects and the resultset must have the name of the users with MemberType equals to 0 and 1 (each on a column).

Here are the rules for MemberType:

- Each project must have one and only one User with MemberType = 0
- Each project must have zero or one User with MemberType = 1
- Each project can have zero or more Users with MemberType = 2 (they won't be returned in this query)

How can I do this preventing multiple rows for the same project?

Here is a sample script to create tables like mine:

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
  Id int,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Project PRIMARY KEY (Id));


CREATE TABLE [User] (
  Id int,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE ProjectMember (
  Project_Id int,
  User_Id int, 
  MemberType tinyint,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ProjectMember PRIMARY KEY(Project_Id, User_Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectMember_Project FOREIGN KEY(Project_Id) REFERENCES Project(Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectMember_User FOREIGN KEY(User_Id) REFERENCES [User](Id));



 INSERT INTO Project(Id, Name) VALUES(1, 'Project 1');
 INSERT INTO Project(Id, Name) VALUES(2, 'Project 2');
 INSERT INTO Project(Id, Name) VALUES(3, 'Project 3');
 INSERT INTO Project(Id, Name) VALUES(4, 'Project 4');


 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(1, 'User 1');
 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(2, 'User 2');
 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(3, 'User 3');
 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(4, 'User 4');
 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(5, 'User 5');
 INSERT INTO [User](Id, Name) VALUES(6, 'User 6');

 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(1, 1, 0);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(1, 2, 1);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(1, 3, 2);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(1, 4, 2);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(1, 5, 2);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(3, 6, 0);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(3, 5, 1);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(4, 3, 0);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(4, 4, 1);
 INSERT INTO ProjectMember(Project_Id, User_Id, MemberType) VALUES(4, 5, 2);
```

And this is how the query is right now:

```
SELECT 
  P.Id, P.Name, Type0.Name as UserType0, Type1.Name as UserType1 
FROM 
Project as P
  LEFT JOIN ProjectMember as PM ON P.Id = PM.Project_Id
  LEFT JOIN [User] as Type0 ON PM.User_Id = Type0.Id AND PM.MemberType = 0
  LEFT JOIN [User] as Type1 ON PM.User_Id = Type1.Id AND PM.MemberType = 1
```

I need my resultset with only row for each Project. I tried changing the JOIN between ProjectMember and User (Type0) to be an INNER JOIN but it caused problems with the JOIN for Type1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  Id, 
        Name, 
        [0] as UserType0, 
        [1] as UserType1 
FROM    (SELECT p.Id, p.Name, u.Name AS UserName, pm.MemberType
         FROM   Project as P
                LEFT JOIN ProjectMember as PM ON P.Id = PM.Project_Id
                LEFT JOIN [User] as U ON PM.User_Id = U.Id 
        ) q
PIVOT (
        MIN(UserName)
        FOR MemberType IN ([0],[1])
) p
```

Comment: Thanks both of you. As the answers were almost the same (I think there's no difference on using MIN or MAX function in this case), I had to accept the first posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt based on my understanding:

```
select id,
       ProjectName,
       [0] as Type0,
       [1] as Type1
from 
(SELECT 
  P.Id, P.Name as projectname, u.Name as username,pm.membertype  
FROM 
Project as P
  LEFT JOIN ProjectMember as PM ON P.Id = PM.Project_Id
  LEFT JOIN [User] as u ON PM.User_Id = u.Id 
 ) t
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX(username) FOR membertype in ([0],[1])
 ) p;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62686/17/0)